How to resolve this Python Snscrape error?
Why am I getting this error on the Snscrape? I have updated the Python and the Snscrape in the real time, both are updated.
PS C:\Users\muzam\OneDrive\Desktop\Summer\project 1> python -u "c:\Users\muzam\OneDrive\Desktop\Summer\project 1\Daraz Sentiment Analysis\tempCodeRunnerFile.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\muzam\OneDrive\Desktop\Summer\project 1\Daraz Sentiment Analysis\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 1, in <module>
    import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
  File "C:\Users\muzam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\snscrape\modules\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>       
    _import_modules()
  File "C:\Users\muzam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\snscrape\modules\__init__.py", line 13, in _import_modules
    module = importer.find_module(moduleName).load_module(moduleName)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'FileFinder' object has no attribute 'find_module'`

My code for this error:
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
import csv
def is_english_textual_tweet(tweet):
    return (
        tweet.lang == 'en' and
        not tweet.retweetedTweet and
        not tweet.inReplyToTweetId and
        not tweet.media
    )
username = 'nfak_ism_'
tweets = []
for tweet in sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(f'from:{username}').get_items():
    if is_english_textual_tweet(tweet):
        tweets.append({
            'date': tweet.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
            'content': tweet.content,
            'id': tweet.id,
            'username': tweet.user.username
        })
csv_file = 'tweets.csv'
with open(csv_file, mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=['date', 'content', 'id', 'username'])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(tweets)

print(f'Scraped {len(tweets)} tweets from @{username}')
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
print(df.head(3))



The problem appears to be your use of Python 3.12.
According to PyPI, snscrape is only supported on Python 3.8 to 3.11. Try downgrading to Python 3.11.
If we take a careful look at your traceback, your code hits an exception at the first line, import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter. Indeed, I found that I get the same error as you merely attempting to import the package in Python 3.12:
Python 3.12.4 (tags/v3.12.4:8e8a4ba, Jun  6 2024, 19:30:16) [MSC v.1940 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import snscrape.modules.twitter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Luke\.virtualenvs\78685974-0LPcIQMG\Lib\site-packages\snscrape\modules\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    _import_modules()
  File "C:\Users\Luke\.virtualenvs\78685974-0LPcIQMG\Lib\site-packages\snscrape\modules\__init__.py", line 13, in _import_modules
    module = importer.find_module(moduleName).load_module(moduleName)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'FileFinder' object has no attribute 'find_module'

On the other hand, with Python 3.11, the package imports fine:
Python 3.11.1 (tags/v3.11.1:a7a450f, Dec  6 2022, 19:58:39) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import snscrape.modules.twitter
>>>

